# How to use SELECT result record as DECODE parameters?

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, decode, oracle8i

Is it possible to use SELECT result as DECODE parameters when this SELECT returns only **one record** with prepared string?
For example:

> SELECT replace(replace(serialized_data)..)..) as result FROM table

Returns following result in ONE ROW:

> 0,'label0',1,'label1',2,'label2'

But when I put this to DECODE it's being interpreted as ONE PARAMETER.
Is there possiblity to convert this result *"string"* to *"pure"* sql code? ;)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is the Decode statement you are trying to implement?

Comment: I'm doing a report, but fields with multiply choice are returning only ID of a choice. And translation of those ID is saved like this: '0=BLACK;1=GREEN;2=YELLOW' (in one column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could kind of replicate `decode` by use of `instr` and `substr`. An example below (which could probably be tidied up considerably but works):

```
select DTXT
      ,Nvl(
         Substr(
           DTXT
          ,Instr(DTXT, SEARCHTXT || VALMTCH)
           + Length(SEARCHTXT || VALMTCH)
          ,  Instr(DTXT, VALSEP, Instr(DTXT, SEARCHTXT || VALMTCH))
           - Instr(DTXT, SEARCHTXT || VALMTCH)
           - Length(SEARCHTXT || VALMTCH))
        ,CASEOTHER)
         as TXTMATCH
  from (select '0=BLACK;1=GREEN;2=YELLOW;' as DTXT
              ,'1' as SEARCHTXT
              ,';' as VALSEP
              ,'=' as VALMTCH
              ,'OTHER' as CASEOTHER
          from Dual)
```

You do need to have a semi-colon (VALSEP) at the end of the text though to ensure you can find the last value (though it's possible to work around that if I looked into it further).

Answer (score 0):

list_agg or wm_concat depending on version of oracle.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm

Comment: thanks. unfortunately I've got 8i so LISTAGG is not available. I'm not sure how to use wm_concat. There's no clear documentation for analytic use, how to convert this result string to array/table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
declare
  DECTXT   varchar2(4000);
begin
  select replace(replace(serialized_data)..)..) as result into dectxt from table;
  execute immediate 'select decode(col1,' || DECTXT || ') from tab1';
end;
```

This is just a quick example, not showing any output, etc.

Comment: @Mack80 - Can you call a stored procedure as this could be placed in a Stored Proc.